Pandas: Get value counts for each column, based off of a group by
I have survey results like below:



ID
Category
Question 1
Question 2




1
A
Agree
Agree


2
A
Disagree
Agree


3
B
Agree
Agree


4
B
Disagree
Disagree



I want to use pandas to get the number of value counts, based off of a group by:



Question
Question 1
Question 1
Question 2
Question 2




Value
Agree
Disagree
Agree
Disagree


Category






A
1
1
2
0


B
1
1
0
1



I've tried:
Pivot Table
df.pivot_table(index='Category', 
   columns=["Question 1","Question 2"],
   aggfunc='size',
   fill_value=0)

But that doesn't separate out the questions, it makes each question a layer in a multi-level index.
Group By
Well, groupby doesn't work, since it produces a single column at the end.
Thanks!

Do it this way:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "Category": ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
    "Question 1": ["Agree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Disagree"],
    "Question 2": ["Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Disagree"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_long = df.melt(id_vars=["ID", "Category"], value_vars=["Question 1", "Question 2"],
                  var_name="Question", value_name="Value")

result = df_long.pivot_table(index="Category", columns=["Question", "Value"], aggfunc="size", fill_value=0)

print(result)

which gives
Question Question 1          Question 2         
Value         Agree Disagree      Agree Disagree
Category                                        
A                 1        1          2        0
B                 1        1          1        1


You can use df.melt and pd.crosstab:

Apply df.melt, setting names for your variable and value columns: 'Question' and 'Value'.
Pipe the result (df.pipe) to apply pd.crosstab, setting columns parameter to a list of your two columns: [x['Question'], x['Value']].

out = (df
       .melt(id_vars='Category',
             value_vars=['Question 1', 'Question 2'],
             var_name='Question',
             value_name='Value'
             )
       .pipe(lambda x: pd.crosstab(index=x['Category'],
                                   columns=[x['Question'], x['Value']]
                                   )
             )
       )

Output
Question Question 1          Question 2         
Value         Agree Disagree      Agree Disagree
Category                                        
A                 1        1          2        0
B                 1        1          1        1

Data
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}, 
        'Category': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B'}, 
        'Question 1': {0: 'Agree', 1: 'Disagree', 2: 'Agree', 3: 'Disagree'}, 
        'Question 2': {0: 'Agree', 1: 'Agree', 2: 'Agree', 3: 'Disagree'}
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


I would suggest that you break it down in chunks - build the groupby output individually - and concatenate the final output:
build the groupby output for Question 1:
A=df.groupby(['Category','Question 1'],sort=False)
A=A.size().unstack(fill_value=0)
A={A.columns.name:A.rename_axis(columns=None)}

build the groupby output for Question 2:
B=df.groupby(['Category','Question 2'],sort=False)
B=B.size().unstack(fill_value=0)
B={B.columns.name:B.rename_axis(columns=None)}

concatenate the dictionary of dataframes:
pd.concat(A|B,axis=1).rename_axis(columns=['Question','Value'])
Question Question 1          Question 2
Value         Agree Disagree      Agree Disagree
Category
A                 1        1          2        0
B                 1        1          1        1


Another solution:
out = (
    df.groupby("Category")[["Question 1", "Question 2"]]
    .apply(lambda x: x.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts())
    .unstack([1, 2])
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
)
print(out)

Prints:
         Question 1          Question 2         
              Agree Disagree      Agree Disagree
Category                                        
A                 1        1          2        0
B                 1        1          1        1


import pandas as pd
import janitor

data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'Question 1': ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', 'Disagree'],
    'Question 2': ['Agree', 'Agree', 'Agree', 'Disagree']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Pivot longer to transform the DataFrame
long_df = (df
           .pivot_longer(
               index=['Category'],
               column_names=['Question 1', 'Question 2'],
               names_to='Question',
               values_to='Response'
           )
          )


print(long_df)
'''
  Category    Question  Response
0        A  Question 1     Agree
1        A  Question 1  Disagree
2        B  Question 1     Agree
3        B  Question 1  Disagree
4        A  Question 2     Agree
5        A  Question 2     Agree
6        B  Question 2     Agree
7        B  Question 2  Disagree
'''
# Now aggregate counts
result1 = (long_df
          .groupby(['Category', 'Question', 'Response'])
          .size()
          .unstack(fill_value=0)
          .reset_index()
         )

print(result1)
'''
Response Category    Question  Agree  Disagree
0               A  Question 1      1         1
1               A  Question 2      2         0
2               B  Question 1      1         1
3               B  Question 2      1         1

'''
result2 = long_df.pivot_table(index="Category", columns=["Question", "Response"], 
                             aggfunc="size", fill_value=0)

print(result2)
'''
Question      Question 1          Question 2         
Response      Agree Disagree      Agree Disagree
Category                                        
A                 1        1          2        0
B                 1        1          1        1
'''

